# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: ado.net

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rd.GetString(2)))
{
    StrBcc = rd.GetString(2);
}
```

> Error:  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This
>   method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Answer (score 24):

My solution was to create an extension method:

```
static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static string GetStringNullCheck(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : reader.GetString(ordinal);
    }
}
```

So I can use it as:

```
 StrBcc = rd.GetStringNullCheck(2);
```

Comment: You probably want to declare the class as `public` for it to be a generally useful extension method.

Answer (score 12):

You should use

```
if (!rd.IsDBNull(2))
    StrBcc = rd.GetString(2);
```

That's because when you use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)` you are telling your app that `x` is a string, while is a database `null` value, which is different from a string whose value is null.

Answer (score 5):

If your values can be **NULL** then using **SqlTypes** instead can be a safer solution as they all implement **INullable**:

```
StrBcc = rd.GetSqlString(2);
```

or if you like extension methods:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueOrNull<T>(this SqlDataReader reader, int ordinal) where T : class
    {
        return !reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal) : null;
    }

    public static T? GetValueOrNullable<T>(this SqlDataReader reader,  int ordinal) where T : struct 
    {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(ordinal)) return null;
        return reader.GetFieldValue<T>(ordinal);
    }
}
```